# Unable to update binary file using pickle in python, please assist

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

Python :Pickle isnt updating the full file

```
    up={}
    f=False
    f1=open("BINARY3.dat","rb+")
    f1.seek(0)
    try:
        while True:
            pos=f1.tell()
            up=pickle.load(f1)                
            if up['Year']<2005:
                up['Status']='Disposed'                   
                f1.seek(pos)
                pickle.dump(up,f1)
                f=True

    except EOFError:
        if f==False:
            print('no record found')
        else:
            print("record")
        f1.close()
```

this is the code snippet where the error is occurring

this is expected output:

```
Enter option: 1-Make/Add Records, 2-Check status of fir, 3-update data, 4-leave: 3
{'Court_est': 'highcourt', 'Police_Station': 'kolkata', 'FIR': 1, 'Year': 2000, 'Status': 'Disposed'}
{'Court_est': 'specialcourt', 'Police_Station': 'pune', 'FIR': 2, 'Year': 2002, 'Status': 'Disposed'}
{'Court_est': 'supremecourt', 'Police_Station': 'delhi', 'FIR': 3, 'Year': 2004, 'Status': 'Disposed'}
```

problem:
it is stopping at the second fir only, the last fir is not getting printed

note: please n kindly answer using pickle module as im still a student.

Comment: You can't update a pickle in the middle of a file.  If the data structure gets longer, you'll trash the records that follow it.  You need to read the WHOLE FILE into memory, update what you need to update, then replace the whole file.